# How to open exact app with Intent.ACTION_VIEW and Uri

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

I am trying to open zoom app by passing uri to the intent with below and it works fine.

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("<zoom url>"))
 val packageManager = packageManager
 if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
     startActivity(launchApp)
 }
```

But this shows my browser also as user can select it and open the uri I pass. what I want to do is only open zoom app with the uri.
By using `val activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)` I can filter the apps that can open my intent but how can I select the exact app(zoom) and pass uri to it and open zoom app only with my meeting url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be need a packageName?

I referenced some code from Google in [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/main/demos/custom-tabs-example-app/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/CustomTabActivityHelper.java)

```
public static void openCustomTab(Activity activity,
                                     CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent,
                                     Uri uri,
                                     CustomTabFallback fallback) {
        String packageName = CustomTabsHelper.getPackageNameToUse(activity);

        //If we cant find a package name, it means theres no browser that supports
        //Chrome Custom Tabs installed. So, we fallback to the webview
        if (packageName == null) {
            if (fallback != null) {
                fallback.openUri(activity, uri);
            }
        } else {
            customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(packageName);
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);
        }
    }
```

it use `setPackage()`,then the app will open the chrome app without chooser.

This is the method of `getPackageNameToUse`

```
static final String STABLE_PACKAGE = "com.android.chrome";
static final String BETA_PACKAGE = "com.chrome.beta";
static final String DEV_PACKAGE = "com.chrome.dev";
static final String LOCAL_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.apps.chrome";

...
...

public static String getPackageNameToUse(Context context) {
        if (sPackageNameToUse != null) return sPackageNameToUse;

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        // Get default VIEW intent handler.
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
        ResolveInfo defaultViewHandlerInfo = pm.resolveActivity(activityIntent, 0);
        String defaultViewHandlerPackageName = null;
        if (defaultViewHandlerInfo != null) {
            defaultViewHandlerPackageName = defaultViewHandlerInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        }

        // Get all apps that can handle VIEW intents.
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedActivityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, 0);
        List<String> packagesSupportingCustomTabs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ResolveInfo info : resolvedActivityList) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_CUSTOM_TABS_CONNECTION);
            serviceIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (pm.resolveService(serviceIntent, 0) != null) {
                packagesSupportingCustomTabs.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }

        // Now packagesSupportingCustomTabs contains all apps that can handle both VIEW intents
        // and service calls.
        if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.isEmpty()) {
            sPackageNameToUse = null;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.size() == 1) {
            sPackageNameToUse = packagesSupportingCustomTabs.get(0);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultViewHandlerPackageName)
                && !hasSpecializedHandlerIntents(context, activityIntent)
                && packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(defaultViewHandlerPackageName)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = defaultViewHandlerPackageName;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(STABLE_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = STABLE_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(BETA_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = BETA_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(DEV_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = DEV_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(LOCAL_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = LOCAL_PACKAGE;
        }
        return sPackageNameToUse;
    }
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. `setPackage()` is the thing which I didn't have idea about.

Comment: I think that the official staff of zoom will be happy to provide their package names! Or through some decompilation tools?

Comment: yeah may be.but we can get those info through `queryIntentActivities()`